# Laravel Voyager: Dropdown that shows conditional relations

Tags: php, admin, backend, voyager

I am using Laravel with Voyager for the back-end.
I made a relationship between Posts model and Categories model.
When adding a new Post, I can choose an according category using a dropdown.

How can I make this dropdown show Categories according to certain conditions? (Let's say, only subcategories)

Comment: is this solved ? If yes can you please post the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can easily filter the shown relationship options by defining a local scope in the foreign model. For example, if you want to only show active entries of categories in a relationship input, create a scope as given in your `Category` model,

```php
public function scopeSubcategories($query){
    return $query->where('parent_id', '!=' , null);
}
```

Now, go to the BREAD builder and add the following to the relationship options

```js
{
    "scope": "subcategories"
}
```

The value is the name of your scope-method without the word scope.
The value for `scopeSubcategories()` is `subcategories`.

Comment: Is this solution working?

Comment: @AkashSethi Yes, give it a try :)